# Moving switched circuit to the other switch in the box using the space gained for an unswitched outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

Two 3 pole circuits control the overhead garage lights. I would like to put them all on 1 switch and add an outlet in the box. ! switch has black, white and red, the other switch has black and white. Also in the box are black and white joined together and taped off. Putting both light circuits on one switch in the box I can get done. How can I use what is there to have constant power to an outlet. The existing lighting circuits are on two different breakers. How does that effect what I am doing.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a few pictures of the switch box wiring and label what you can?

Comment: Yeah, we really need to see the existing wiring.  The fact that it is 2 different circuits is very important.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring inside the boxes involved please?

Comment: If the lighting is on 2 separate circuits can they be combined to a single circuit total wattage? If the total wattage is low enough are all the switches in the same locations? If not smart switches may be needed to combine them with existing wiring.  Adding a receptacle will depend if that is the location that the power enters the circuit. Power could come in at the light or the other switch, we need photos of the wiring or a schematic of how wired and the total load on the existing circuits to be able to provide advice.